# How to duplicate items in Adobe Xd while also adding spacing like in Sketch?

Tags: shortcuts, adobe-xd

One of my favorite keyboard shortcuts in Sketch is the duplicate items <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> as explained [here](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/saving-time-in-sketch-7042142c8a8e). In Adobe XD the same option is [available](https://www.xdguru.com/adobe-xd-guide/duplicating-objects/), however it duplicates the items in the exact same position as the master item.

Is there a keyboard shortcut where I can do the same in XD as I can do in Sketch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicate functionality you're describing does not exist in XD. However, the easiest two options for easily duplicating objects are the Repeat Grid feature, and using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut.

**Repeat Grid**

Select the object and then enable Repeat Grid (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>). Note that items in the repeat grid are linked, meaning that any change to an object within the repeat grid will also apply to the others.

[image: repeat grid]

**Alt + Shift**

Hold and drag the object while pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. If you're working with more than 2 objects that require the same padding/margin, you will see helpful guides that let you snap to the same spacing. I personally find this method to be the fastest and most efficient.

[image: alt shift]

Answer (score 0):

The new way of Duplicating component while adding spacing in Adobe XD is using **"Stacks and duplicating (CMD/CTRL + D)"**

**Starter shapes** (Alt + drag)

[image]

**Grouping** (Select whole then Ctrl + G)

[image]

**Stacks and Duplicating** (Horizontal and Vertical stacking available)

1. Right pane Stack option select
2. Left Double click element to duplicate then CMD/CTRL + D

[image]